# Unable to receive message on tab from background script

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wrote this script to send a message from a background script to a script in a new tab but for some reason, the script in the tab isn't receiving the message. Is this a problem with my script or my browser (Firefox 62.0.3)

my "manifest":

```
{
"manifest_version":2,
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "this is a test extension",

"background":{
"scripts": ["OnButtonClick.js"]
},

"permissions": [

 "tabs"

],

"content_scripts": [{

"matches": ["www.youtube.com"],
"js": ["input.js"]

}],

"browser_action": {

"default_icon": "button.png",
"default_title": "test button"
}

}
```

my "OnButtonClick.js":

```
function action(){

  browser.tabs.create({
    url: "www.youtube.com"  
});

browser.tabs.sendMessage(1,{"message":"hi"})

}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(action);
```

and my "input.js":

```
function handleMessage(msg){
    console.log(msg);

}

 browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage)
```

Answer (score 1):

`browser.tabs.create()` is a asynchronous therefore, `browser.tabs.sendMessage()` runs even before a tab is created.

You have to wait for it to run first.

Here are some suggestions:

```
// first create the tab 
const newTab = browser.tabs.create({
  url: 'https://example.org'
});
newTAb.then(onCreated, onError);

// after tab is created 
function onCreated(tab) {
  browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{message: 'hi'});
}
// in case of error
function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

// above can also be written as this
browser.tabs.create({
  url: 'https://example.org'
}).then(
  tab => browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{message: 'hi'}),
  error => console.log(error)
); 

// another alternative for above
browser.tabs.create({url: 'https://example.org'})
.then(tab => browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{message: 'hi'}))
.catch(error => console.log(error));

// Using chrome and callback function
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://example.org'}, tab =>
  browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{message: 'hi'})
);

// same as above, all with chrome
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://example.org'}, tab =>
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{message: 'hi'})
);
```

You can also use `async/await` but that may make it more complicated in this case.

**Update on comment:**
`content_scripts` by default run at `"document_idle"` (corresponds to complete. The document and all its resources have finished loading.)

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["www.youtube.com"],
  "js": ["input.js"]
}],
```

Therefore, the `input.js` is injected once everything is loaded. However, the `sendMessage()` runs as soon as tab is created and thus there is no listener to listen to its message.

In your simple example, that can be fixed by `"run_at": "document_start"`

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["www.youtube.com"],
  "js": ["input.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}],
```

However, if `input.js` needs to access DOM after receiving message, then you need to add a `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and run it after the document is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for all your time, but it still isn't working for some reason. My "input.js" isn't even acessing DOM (although I plan on doing that in the future) so I guess I'll just keep sniffing around for more answers.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to use "sendMessage"?
you can use this code

```
browser.tabs.executeScript(tabID, {    code: "func()" /* your function in content script*/,frameId:0 /* for send to all frame or put id for use a special frame id*/});
```

or this code as file

```
browser.tabs.executeScript(tabID, {    file: "/filename.js",frameId:0});
```

Comment: Because I plan on passing a link to the tab as an argument. So I have to send it via "sendMessage" and receive it in the tab script.

Comment: What is the tabID of the active tab?

Comment: You can get active tab id with  =>
chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true},function(tab){console.debug(tab[0].id);})